# C++ Builder determining optional SOAP property has been set

Tags: c++builder

I have a soap client generated with the WSDL importer. Some of the response types have optional fields. For these fields extra boolean fields are generated to track if they have been set but these are private. Here is a minimal example of what is being generated.

```
class SomeType : public TRemotable {
private:
  int    FValue;
  bool            FValue_Specified;
  void __fastcall SetValue(int Index, int _prop_val)
  {  FValue = _prop_val; FValue_Specified = true;  }
public:
  __property int Value = { index=(IS_OPTN), read=FValue, write=SetValue, stored = Value_Specified };
};
```

I want to be able to read `FValue_Specified` because sometimes I need to distinguish between not set and the default value.

Version is C++ Builder Alexandria 11.3